# Combining and Splitting Words in Sanskrit

Tags: bhagavad-gita, sanskrit

I am trying to learn and apply some basic word combining and splitting rules. Consider  the first word in verse 15.7 from the Bhagavata Gita.

> > **ममैवांशो** जीवलोके जीवभूत: सनातन: |
> > मन:षष्ठानीन्द्रियाणि प्रकृतिस्थानि कर्षति ||

I am pretty sure that the compound word splits as follows:

> > ममैवांशो = ममो (mamo) + ईवा (eva)  + अंशो (ansho, or part)

Let us consider the following split whose meaning does not really make sense from the context. Is this valid to have the extra अ in the splitting according to the rules of Sanskrit grammar?

> > ममैवांशो = ममो  (mamo) + ईवा (eva) + अ (a, or negation) + अंशो (ansho, or part)

Comment: This is not really about the Hindu religion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about Sanskrit so better suited to the Linguistics Stack Exchange but the correct sandhi viccheda is as follows:

ममैवांशो = मम + एव + अंशः

There is no real ambiguity here, one just needs to know that only set of the possible components are actual Sanskrit words, which comes through learning and experience.

ममो + ईवा + अंशो are not even real Sanskrit words, neither will they create ममैवांशो after sandhi. If there was an अ in there, its elision after sandhi would be marked with an avagraha in writing, but in your example ममो + ईवा + अ + अंशो, it doesn't even make grammatical sense since अ is not a word and if used to negate अंशः it would be अनंशः instead.

Comment: Thank you very much